# Joining multiple tables into a single view and using it int stored procedure will affect the performance?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a view which is combining 6 tables using UNION. In my stored procedure I am calling that view and fetching the data then applying some inner join. Will it affect performance of the application?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much data is in those tables and if there are indexes applied to the tables.